# Wordpress plugin for guest edits like Wikipedia?

Tags: wordpress, wiki

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin where users can edit the published posts, and at the back end, I can approve or reject those edits just like Wikipedia does.

*Now why this requirement?*

English is not my native language and I may go wrong with the grammar while posting, so it would be better if the community peer reviews it and edit whenever required, and later, those edits can be approved from the back end by admin.

Requirements :

- Front End edit button where user can edit a post without logging in with a decent markdown editor where they cannot enter any malicious inputs.
- Show a queue of edited posts on the back end
- Approve or Reject button for the edits made by guest users
- Rolling back functionality to a particular edit

Comment: Some ideas: [Best Wordpress wiki plugin? (...) - Web Hosting Talk](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1020829) (same post here: [WordPress > Support >> Best wordpress wiki plugin? (...)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/best-wordpress-wiki-plugin-mediawiki-wp-wiki-vs-bp-group-wiki-comparisons))

Comment: @nidunc I've read many posts online before asking, the plugins they refer are either too old, or they are not actively developed.

Comment: [WP Errata](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-errata/) could be another option, although it is a bit out of date at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to log in, how fast before the site becomes destroyed by spammers?

If you want to add this functionality for confirmed users, all you need to do is make the default user role ***editor***, and anyone will then be able to edit and post anything they want. Revisions will be stored normally.

[image]